When using CameraPreview, the camera screen is in Landscape mode and the Aspect Ratio is slightly off
Problem:
When using CameraPreview, the camera screen is in Landscape mode and the Aspect Ratio is slightly off. This is quite strange because the same code works fine in other projects.
What could be the fundamental solution to this issue? I'm looking for a resolution that goes beyond simply using Transform.rotate.
Here is my code
SystemChrome.setPreferredOrientations(
    [
      DeviceOrientation.portraitUp,
      DeviceOrientation.portraitDown,
    ],
  );

main.dart
Future<void> initializeCamera() async {
    try {
      _availableCameras = await availableCameras();

      debugPrint('✅ _availableCameras : ${_availableCameras![0]} ');

      if (_availableCameras!.isNotEmpty) {
        final controller = CameraController(
          _availableCameras![_selectedCameraIndex],
          ResolutionPreset.max,
          enableAudio: false,
        );

        await controller.initialize();
        await controller.lockCaptureOrientation(DeviceOrientation.portraitUp);
        state = controller; // Set the state with the initialized controller
        debugPrint('✅ camera initialized ');
      }
    } catch (e) {
      state = null; // If there's an error, set the state to null
    }
  }

controller.dart
...
 
body: CameraPreview(cameraController!)

... 

some_page.dart
and this is what it looks like

Can you help me ?
I'm using macOs_Desktop, android , ios
I tried chatGPT and google search but doesn't work for me

I solved the problem anyway.
I don't think it's a code issue.
I changed the package version from ^0.11.0+2 to 0.10.6, and it works fine now.
If you encounter the same bug, try downgrading until a recent update fixes it.
Happy coding 

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
